# Is there a FREE Java GUI designer?

Tags: java, swing, open-source, gui-designer

Is there a FREE (or relatively cheaper) Java GUI designer/builder?

Comment: Just for the record Open Source != Free :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I highly recommend [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/)'s Matisse GUI editor.

Comment: I recommend this one as well... its very easy to use, and powerful.

Comment: I personally have used this one pretty from its early days, I have yet to find a GUI design it cannot at least "rough out"

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it looks like the Eclipse Visual Editor has not been maintained or developed a lot the past three years. On the [Visual Editor homepage](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/WebContent/main.php) you'll see that the last release is from June 30, 2006 - more than three years ago.

The best free GUI builder for Java at the moment is probably Matisse which is included in NetBeans, as others have already mentioned.

If you're an Eclipse user, then there's also [Matisse4MyEclipse](http://www.myeclipseide.com/index.php?module=htmlpages&func=display&pid=5), but it is not free - it's an add-on to the popular MyEclipse. Another non-free option for Eclipse is [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.instantiations.com/windowbuilder/), which is not only for Swing, but also for SWT and even GWT GUIs.

Comment: WindowBuilder Pro is now available for free.

Comment: Yes, Google bought it and now had made it available for free.

Answer (score 3):

Try [**WindowBuilder**](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/), which once was a non-free Eclipse plugin, and is now available for free.

WindowBuilder has changed hands several times in the last 12 months ([from Instantiations to Google](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/09/google-relaunches-instantiations.html), followed by [Google giving it to the Eclipse Foundation](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/12/windowbuilder-becomes-new-open-source.html)).

It is available for free from the [Eclipse WindowBuilder page](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/).

Answer (score 2):

[Netbeans has one](http://www.j2ee.me/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/nb/index.html), as does [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/WebContent/main.php).

Comment: If I remember right, if you don't want to fork out any money, Eclipse has no capabilities for using GroupLayout; NetBeans has support for GroupLayout out of the box.

Comment: NetBeans is a lot easier to use than Eclipse for GUI designing in my opinion. Less hassle with configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't free (or particularly cheap), but the one in [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html) is pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

try [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) or Eclipse [Visual Editor Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/WebContent/main.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try netbeans, I'm sure you're gonna like the latest release (version 6.7)

Answer (score 0):

You should go for 
 [ecllipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) ,[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) and Netbeans if you want it for free.

But i recoment  Jbuider  which expensive but really good GUI environment.